# 4 HDMI display via USB

Tags: usb, display, pi-4

I want to use 4 HDMI small display modules on raspberry pi 4, but if i supply enough power to power on 4 display to raspberry pi, will display modules work well?
Those 4 display modules will act as one big display, not duplicating screen
I'm trying to make dividable monitor, so i can't use one big monitor

Comment: You'll need two RPi4B 2GBs to do that. Then install https://piwall.co.uk (if it's still alive) to get the multi screen stuff running.

Comment: Can i use usb hub and hdmi->usb adaptor?

Comment: piwall.co.uk :  looks like it's a goner.

Comment: Probably not for the USB adapter. Try it - it won't hurt.